# Macbook not shutting down due to a stuck app

Tags: macos, mojave, performance, shutdown

I was trying to mount my server with Osxfuse but the server was offline but the cursor turned into a colorful loading icon and I wasn't able to click anything. Was only able too move the cursor. So I closed the laptop. Then opened it again and now the cursor is not moving and still shows that loading icon.

Keyboard lights are off now. **Keyboard and trackpad are unresponsive.**

I've tried holding the power button(Touch ID) for long enough but it's still not shutting down. Should I wait until battery runs out or what should I do?

Comment: Hi and welcome! here's our quick [tour]. **1** See if menu bar works in any application and Click on apple icon and then Force quit. A window appears and then kill the app. Shortcut for the same is cmd+alt+esc. **2** I dont understand *keyboard lights are off now*. See if the keyboard brightness buttons caused this. **3** If keyboard works, You can try activity monitor too.

Comment: @ankii Keyboard and trackpad are unresponsive. I've tried holding the Touch ID power button several times but it didn't work.

Comment: @user8481790: Unplug all accessories and power cables. Try holding down the power/TouchID button for 30 seconds. Does this shutdown the computer?

Comment: @drivec No. That is why I'm asking questions here.